# How do I calculate the maximum gap for one fluid to flow through and not another

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow

I'm kinda new to fluid dynamics and all I know (which is very little) is from self education, so it might be wrong and also the reason I can't find the answer to my question. I'm trying to determine how big a gap needs to be to let air out and keep plastic in. This happens often and is a common practice in the injection moulding of plastics, called venting. This is so that the air of the mould will get out before the plastic arrives. Otherwise due to the high pressure you get the same effect as in a diesel engine and burn your plastic. Most of the time mould engineers use a rule of thumb for determining this gap to let the air out and keep the plastic in but I can't seem to shake of the feeling that this can be a more precise business.

Can someone please help as I'm no further then the idea this has something to do with the pressure inside the mold with a relation to the viscosity of the air and the plastic. I have no clue how to proceed or what formulas I need.

Thanks a lot for any input!

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate this from first principles, but it would be a complex process with approximations in it. In this case, experience is the best teacher, and sitting down for a chat over coffee with an experienced moldmaker would be a much better use of your time. Plus it would demonstrate to the the moldmaker that you respect his judgement and experience, which is always a good thing on the factory floor.